# nautilus-open-terminal on 11.10 kills nautilus

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

After I installed nautilus-open-terminal, when I clicked the icon on unity panel to open my /home folder, the folder just stayed there for no more than 10 sec and then disappered. So I removed it, and it is OK now. But the language input icon disappered, and I used unity --reset. Is this a bug?

Comment: This is a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-open-terminal/+bug/865115

Comment: @snowhawkyrf Thanks for tracing it down to nautilus-open-terminal. I was about to remove all kinds of nautilus related packages and your post saved me from doing that.